# Inner join 3 tables, retrieve if conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have three tables

```
Person
- id
- other_fields

PersonTypes
- id 
- person_id
- type_id

PersonEmails
- id
- person_id
- email_address
```

How to get only these email addresses where PersonTypes.type_id is different than `value` ?
I'm using MariaDB v.10, I tried to use left outer joins with in all tables and then return only these rows where type_id is different. But I'm not sure about the results.

```
SELECT pe.email_address
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonTypes pt ON p.id = pt.person_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonEmails pe ON p.id = pe.person_id
WHERE pt.type_id != 14;
```

Comment: Can you show us your request sample ?

Comment: Yes, I added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select P1.id,
       P2.type_id, -- just for the sake of this output
       P2.email_address
from Person P1
inner join
    (
    select PT.person_id, PT.type_id, PE.email_address
    from PersonTypes PT
    inner join PersonEmails PE
      on PE.person_id = PT.person_id
    where PT.type_id <> 14
    ) P2
  on P2.person_id = P1.id
```

or

```
select pe.email_address
from PersonEmails pe
where person_id not in 
    (
    select person_id
    from PersonTypes
    where Type_id = 14
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question - does it cover the case when PersonTypes can be empty ? Then email_addres should be returned

Comment: @kxyz the second one does

Answer (score 0):

The query selects all persons that don't have type_id 14 and joins Person and PersonsEmails tables data

```
SELECT pe.email_address
FROM PersonTypes pt
INNER JOIN Person p ON pt.person_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN PersonEmails pe ON pt.person_id = pe.person_id
WHERE pt.type_id != 14;
```

Comment: This does not cover case where PersonTypes is empty.
Sorry I din't mention about this above.